# calculating variance using python: "float" object not iterable

Tags: python

I need to make a function to calculate the variance of a list of numbers. I've made a function to calculate the mean, which I am using later in my variance function, but I can't get my variance function to work.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

def mean(a):  
    q = 0   
    for x in a:
        q += x
    return (1.0*q)/len(a)

def variance(a):
    for x in a:
        i = x - mean(a)
        c = i**2
        d = sum(c)
        v = d /len(a)
    return v
print variance(a)
```

I have a "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable" in my 13th line.

I know that the functions I am designing may not be the best, but my mean function works and I am working at a very basic level.

Comment: Not directly an answer to the question, but you should directly go ahead and use python 3 (if possible). Not sure in what context you are coding this.

Comment: What do you think `sum(c)` means, with `c = i**2`?

Comment: `sum(c)` is not meaningful when `c` is a single number.

Comment: What did you define `q = 0` for in `variance`? You are not using it. Did you mean `d = 0` and then `d += c` instead of `d = sum(c)`?

Comment: I left the q=0 in by accident, I knew I needed a similar expression somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to do.  Note the lack of sum(c).

See numpy implementation of the variance for comparison.

```
import numpy as np
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

def mean(a):  
    q = 0   
    for x in a:
        q += x
    return (1.0*q)/len(a)

def variance(a):
    q = 0
    d = 0
    for x in a:
        i = x - mean(a)
        c = i**2
        d = d+c

    v = d /len(a)
    return v

print (variance(a))
print(np.var(a))
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why using `sum(c)` does not work?

Comment: What is the point of `q = 0` in the definition of variance? Also, it is inefficient to recompute `mean(a)` in each pass through the loop. Those were OP's poor design decisions, but a good answer could address them.

Comment: @wilberox Pretty good for just three hours! Good luck with your learning.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start off by explaining the `get_mean` function. Passing a list as a parameter, this function sums all the elements of the list and divides this sum by the total number of elements in the list.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

def get_mean(ls):
    return sum(ls)/len(ls)
```

The `get_variance` function is a tad more complicated to understand. We pass the same argument, a list, as in the `get_mean` function. First, we call the `get_mean` function previously defined to get the mean of the list. We use a list comprehension which iterates over the elements in our list (i.e., [i for i in ls] will return each element i of the list ls) to find the square difference with each element and the mean. The list comprehension returns a list. Because of this, we can calculate the sum of these square differences list and divide the total sum by the length of the list to get the population variance.

```
def get_variance(ls):
    mean = get_mean(ls)
    square_differences = [(i - mean)**2 for i in ls]
    return sum(square_diffences)/len(ls)
```

Now, when we call our `get_variance` function by passing `a` as a parameter, it passes a into our `get_mean` function and then returns the population variance.

```
get_variance(a)
```

Comment: Maybe the list comprehension was a bit much for a beginner, but how is the mean function complex?

Comment: @EAB calling `get_mean` several times in `get_variance` is not efficient

Comment: True. I had it out initially. Let me fix it :)

Comment: @EAB I don't get the syntax yet, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that may work using only one callable (defaults to "mean")--

```py
def get_moment(iterable, order=1, sample=False):

    assert order > 0 and type(order) == int \
        and len(iterable) >= 2

    _mean = sum(iterable) / len(iterable)

    if order == 1:
        return _mean

    else:
        if not sample:
            return sum((datum**order) - _mean
                for datum in iterable
            ) / len(iterable)
        else:
            return sum((datum**order) - _mean
                for datum in iterable
            ) / (len(iterable) - 1)
```